# To find difference between two pivoted columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

```
select count(*) AS id_CNT, Date, price
from table
where Date in ('2019-12-18', '2019-12-19')
  and Id = '-3'
group by Date, price
pivot
    (max(price) for date in (['2019-12-18'], ['2019-12-19']) piv)
```

I have tried this script but what is the next step to get the desired output shown here:

[image: image contains data how it looks and what is the excepted result]

Answer (score 0):

- Make your main query nested and alias(`t`) it
- Remove quotes, keep square brackets for the date literals to create column names
- Remove quotes also for `ID = '-3'` assuming Id is an integer value
- Using `Date in ('2019-12-18', '2019-12-19')` is redundant, so get rid
  of them
- Alias of pivoted part should be after closing parentheses

So, Use this query :

```
    SELECT piv.*, [2019-12-19] - [2019-12-18] as Diff 
      FROM
      (
       SELECT ID, Date, Price, COUNT(*) AS ID_Cnt
         FROM tab
        WHERE ID = -3
        GROUP BY ID, Date, price   
      ) t
      PIVOT
      (
       MAX(Price) for Date in ( [2019-12-18], [2019-12-19] )
      ) piv
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=fc1b3ef533bbf069f0354ba94d580da5)</kbd>

*From the query format which includes square brackets for literals after `in` operator I suppose your DBMS is **SQL-Server**.*

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to PIVOT then UNPIVOT to get that final result when there's only 2 dates.

**Sample data:**

> ```
> create table YourTable
> (
>   Id int not null,
>   [Date] date not null,
>   price decimal(16,2) not null
> )
>
> insert into YourTable
> (id, [date], price) values
> (-3, '2019-12-18', 94416.68),
> (-3, '2019-12-19', 31352.26);
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> WITH CTE_DATA AS
> (
>   SELECT Id, [Date]
>   , id_count = COUNT(*)
>   , price = SUM(price)
>   , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
>   FROM YourTable
>   WHERE Id = -3
>   AND [Date] IN ('2019-12-18', '2019-12-19')
>   GROUP BY Id, [Date]
> )
> SELECT [Date], Id
> , CAST(id_count AS VARCHAR(30)) AS id_count
> , price
> FROM CTE_DATA
> UNION ALL
> SELECT null, null, 'Result'
> , (MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN price END) 
>  - MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN price END))
> FROM CTE_DATA
> GROUP BY Id
> ORDER BY Id desc, [Date]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Date                |   Id | id_count | price    
> :------------------ | ---: | :------- | :--------
> 18/12/2019 00:00:00 |   -3 | 1        | 94416.68 
> 19/12/2019 00:00:00 |   -3 | 1        | 31352.26 
> null                | null | Result   | -63064.42
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=80d07b6a2e805425a713a21dfea12938)*